# Avoiding Landing Page Redirects with SSL in Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, centos7

I'm using SSL for my server configuration. After that, when user access our website it's slightly tough, almost takes significant time to access. And try PageSpeed Insight, the result suggest me to avoid landing page redirect.

```
Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs.

http://example.com/
https://example.com/
https://www.example.com/
```

This being new issue for me.

We use latest Nginx. Here my full configuration in server blocks:

```
server {
       listen           80;
       server_name  example.com www.example.com;
       return           301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.key;
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen 443 ssl spdy;
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomain$

       server_name www.example.com
       root   /home/domain;
       index  index.html index.php index.htm;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.key;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
       ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
       ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GC$
       ssl_session_timeout 1d;
       ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
       ssl_stapling on;
       ssl_stapling_verify on;

       location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
        }



  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /home/domain;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME/home/domain$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Will you be able to post full conf file?

Comment: I've updated my conf, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the redirect in your :80 block to the final redirect to avoid the needless redirect to https://example.com

```
server {
       listen           80;
       server_name  example.com www.example.com;
       --return           301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
       ++return           301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Also, I recommend adding the same set of SSL related directives to the server_name example.com block. Using your example,

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.key;
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

should be

```
server {
        --listen 443 ssl;
        ++listen 443 ssl spdy;
        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.key;
        ++add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomain$
        ++ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ++ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ++ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GC$
        ++ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ++ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ++ssl_stapling on;
        ++ssl_stapling_verify on;
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, i don't know why you added two different connection to server to connect SSL via www and without www. it can be write within one statement.

Why you are using 301 redirect in SSL, somehow you already force with or www redirection to https.

I have also added rewrite rule to redirect with or without www connections to https & removed the 301 return rule.

Here is the final code, try it out if doesn't work let me know i have another one ready for you.

```
server {
   listen           80;
   server_name      example.com www.example.com;
   rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;       
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl spdy;
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomain$
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   root   /home/domain;
   index  index.html index.php index.htm;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.key;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GC$
   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
   ssl_stapling on;
   ssl_stapling_verify on;

   location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /home/domain;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME/home/domain$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your code, but it seems if I use your suggestion, I have old issue, because it's direct to non www domain, which is in the case we need make position our domain in www.